# Convert Function Call to Lambda (SAM)

Tags: android, kotlin

In an android program, I have the following code:

```
clockCheckBox.setOnClickListener((object: View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(view: View): Unit {
        if (clockCheckBox.isChecked())
            enableClocks()
        else
            disableClocks()
    }
}))
```

In Android Studio, a tooltip comes up that says,

> This inspection reports an anonymous object literal implementing a
>   java interface with single abstract method that can be converted into
>   call with lambda expression.

I have tried to do this, but all I get is syntax errors.  Can you show me the correct syntax?  I should perhaps explain that this code is in the `onCreate` method of my activity and clockCheckBox is a local variable defined as

```
val clockCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.clockCheckBox) as CheckBox
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code above can simplify as below:

```
//                v--- parentheses is unnecessary
setOnClickListener {
    //                        v--- boolean property parenthess is unnecessary
    if (clockCheckBox.isChecked)
        enableClocks()
    else
        disableClocks()
}
```

you can see [Java Interoperability](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html) as further.

Answer (score 5):

It's useful to take a close look at the inspection report while understanding the conventions of Kotlin.

> This inspection reports an **anonymous object literal implementing a java interface with single abstract method** *(emphasis mine)* that can be converted into call with lambda expression.

One of the keys in this report is "implementing a java interface with a single abstract method".  This is key because anonymous objects implementing these kinds of interfaces can be succinctly written as just a lambda.  In other words, you can skip the anonymous object literal and the name of the interface and just use a lambda that conforms to the single abstract method's signature.

In the case of the onClick, the equivalent signature is

```
    (view: View) -> Unit
```

So the lambda for your example would be

```
{ view -> if (clockCheckBox.isChecked) enableClocks() else disableClocks() }
```

But since you are not using 'view' in your lambda body, 'view ->' can be omitted.  Instead of view, you are using clockCheckBox (which is a View in the closure for the lambda).

Lastly, when ever a function call's last parameter is a lambda,  instead of writing

```
myFun( { ... } )
```

You can instead write

```
myFun { ... }
```

In other words, you are moving the last parameter, the lambda, outside of the parenthesis (the parentheses can be omitted if there is only one parameter). So your complete example using a lambda would be

```
clockCheckBox.setOnClickListener { 
    if(clockCheckBox.isChecked()) enableClocks() else disableClocks()
}
```

Comment: Great explanation, @Les!  I keep forgetting that: (1) lambdas can be moved outside of parentheses, and (2) parentheses can be removed if there are no parameters remaining, which is why I get confused that function/method calls **seem** to be acting like function/method definitions with the simple `myFun { ... }` syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The way to convert it is to leave only the interface name and the code inside the function. A picture (example in this case) is worth a thousand words so that's how it'll look like:

```
clockCheckBox.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
    if (clockCheckBox.isChecked())
        enableClocks()
    else
        disableClocks()
})
```

You can read more about it on the [kotlin docs page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions).